# Violent riddle with happy end

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

We are two sisters.
Our difference is your best key.
I am probably the bigger one
and everything I’m not,
is she.

We have always opposite opinions,
the reason of our loud fights.
And if I start a quarrel with my sister,
surely, you’ll see and hear
our spites.

The root of our conflict is quite old.
(Yes, we’re born in weird family.)
As kids we fought once, so I’m told.
And then what’s left was
only me.

Comment: Welcome back, and nice riddle! I guess there must be some significance to the moving of the last 2 words in each verse to a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of

> a quantity of matter and a smaller mass of anti-matter.

Two sisters, difference, everything I'm not:

> Matter and anti-matter are related but opposite.

The bigger one:

> In your puzzle, there's more matter.

Opposite opinions, loud fights, quarrel, hear:

> Matter and anti-matter have opposite properties and react energetically to each other.

Root of conflict, family, fight, remainder:

> When matter and anti-matter react, they annihilate an equal amount of each other, so some of the initially more massive type will remain after the other has been completely used up.

Comment: [_As kids we fought once, so I’m told. And then what’s left was only me_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry)

Comment: Yepp, that's it. All the clues match.